# How to retrieve attribute from xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I have the following xml in `XmlDocument`. I am trying to extract the `className` from it.

```
<Registration className="Eng" type="DirectRegistration" state="Activated"     xmlns="http://xyz/Registration">
  <Fields>
    <Field type="abc" value="123456" />
    <Field type="xyz" value="789" />
  </Fields>
</Registration>
```

I have tried the following code but its not giving me `className`.

```
var xmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
```

Can anyone help me to get the value of `className` out.

Many Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is probably one of the most common requests discussed in numerous questions already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
var className = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("className");
```

`xmlDoc.DocumentElement` gives you the *whole* element; `GetAttribute` pulls an individual named attribute from it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
// Trying to parse the given file path to an XML
XmlReader firstXML = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath);
firstXML.ReadToFollowing("Registration");
firstXML.MoveToAttribute("className");
var res = firstXML.Value;
```

`res` will hold "className" value.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use xPath to retrieve the attribute

```
string className = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//Registration/@className").Value;
```